# Consolidated Download Statistics For Python Packages With pip-install

Tags: python, download, package, pip, nuget-package

Is there a way to obtain statistics on how many times a package (every package) has been installed using pip-install or any other package manager?

This question came about when trying to determine the popularity of some python packages I was looking into using for a personal project - I am sure developers would find it useful to be able to obtain such statistics.

Answer (score 6):

You can view the download statistics from the official PyPI data. This data is stored in BigQuery (see https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/the-psf:pypi)

But I developed a page to facilitate this information, take a look at http://pepy.tech/ :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can get this statistics via vanity:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vanity